# Issue in implementing button safeguard on ItemControls in C# WPF App, MVVM structure

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I am trying to build a WPF application with an MVVM pattern following Caliburn micro convention. I have a PersonModel class where three properties are declared. Then in the ShellViewModel class, I created a BindableCollection where I loaded information of 3 person models. In the XAML, I am using ItemControl to create a template of three textboxes so that all 3 person data is shown in 3 different rows.

I have another two buttons, to add and remove PersonModel from BindableCollection and in return, the XAML is also updated. So far, it is working fine.
Now I created another button called "Apply" in ShellViewModel; upon pressing that, it should process an operation in all available BindableCollection.

The issue is, I am trying to implement a Button safeguard for Apply button (CanApply) which only activate if it finds all textboxes are filled for all BindableCollection.
Now I notice if I change/updated any textbox in XAML, it notify the binded property in PersonModel Class, but I need this notification in ShellViewModel where the BindableCollection and CanApply() are defined.

**PersonModel**

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel
    {
        public BindableCollection<PersonModel> People { get; set; }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            People = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>() {
                new PersonModel { FirstName = "John", LastName= "Smith", Age = 30},
                new PersonModel { FirstName = "Bob", LastName= "Marry", Age = 21},
                new PersonModel { FirstName = "", LastName= "Milito", Age = 16}
                };
        }

        public void AddPerson()
        {
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
            //int maxId = 0;

            if (People.Count > 0)
            {
                People.Add(new PersonModel());
            }

        }

        public void RemovePerson()
        {
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

            if (People.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            PersonModel randomPerson = dataAccess.GetRandomItem(People.ToArray());

            People.Remove(randomPerson);
        }

        
        public bool CanApply() {
            bool output = false;
            foreach (var item in People) {
                output = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName)) {
                    output = true;
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
        
        public void Apply() {

        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemoUI.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDemoUI.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="20" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button x:Name="AddPerson">Add New Person</Button>
            <Button x:Name="RemovePerson" Margin="10 0 0 0">Remove Random Person</Button>
            <Button x:Name="Apply" Margin="10 0 0 0">Apply</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <ItemsControl x:Name="People" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" Padding="10">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You usually use commands for this. Commands expose a CanExecute method that controls whether the Button is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this is using an implementation of `ICommand` that lives in your MVVM framework of choice. However, Caliburn.Micro doesn't seem to have commands. Instead, they have something called actions, but the capabilites are very similar. Here's an example of implemention a button click method (`SayHello`) along with a condition for it (`CanSayHello`) taken straight out of [Caliburn.Micro's docs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions):

```cs
using System.Windows;

public class ShellViewModel : IShell
{
    public bool CanSayHello(string name)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name);
    }

    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello {0}!", name));
    }
}
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn.Micro.HelloParameters.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" />
        <Button Content="Click Me">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SayHello">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=Text}" />
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The way this works according to the docs is:

> When a handler is found for the `SayHello` message, it will check to see if that class also has either a property or a method named `CanSayHello`